# invalid arithmetic operator in if condition in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I tried:

```
if [[ ${numbers[4]} -ge $best_res ]]; then
                             ...
fi
```

I got the following error for the if condition line:

```
7 ./q1.sh: line 58: [[: 0.346: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".346")
```

there are similar questions, but my error is in "if" condition. How can I fix it with "bc" or "dc"?

Comment: Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) doesn't support floating point arithmetic, which is what one of your variables appears to have.

Here's simple example:

```
$ [[ 0.346 -ge 0 ]] && echo "true"
bash: [[: 0.346: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".346")
```

You'll have to use external tools like [`bc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bc.1p.html) or [`dc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dc), etc.

Comment: Okay, but how I can have bc in if condition

Comment: With `bc`, you could do: `$ a=0.346; b=0; echo "$a > $b" | bc` which prints 0 or 1 (in this case 1).